# Where is ngx bootstrap documentation for an input?

Tags: ngx-bootstrap

I can't believe I am asking such a simple question, but i've spent 10 minutes scouring this site: https://ngx-universal.herokuapp.com/getting-started just to find how to style a simple input element and I can not find it anywhere.

10 minutes is about 9 minutes and 55 seconds longer than it should have taken...

(day 2 no response...   bueller?)

Comment: ngx-bootstrap doesn't work with styles at all, it's just an implementation of bootstrap components in native angular code. All styles and markup should be taken from https://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: @IlyaSurmay you should post this as the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ngx-bootstrap` doesn't work with styles at all, it's just an implementation of bootstrap components in native angular code. All styles and markup should be taken from [getbootstrap.com](http://getbootstrap.com)

Comment: Looks get bootstrap.com internally depends on Jquery and do we need to put Jquery in Angular 2 project?

Comment: Not at all :) if you are using ngx-bootstrap, everything is wrapped nicely into Angular elements you can use out of the box